# How should i parse this JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What would be the best way to parse this JSON object into a data object in Objective C?

```
    {
      "Properties" : {
        "Property1" : {
            "min" : 70.0,
            "max" : 70.0
        },
        "Property2" : {
            "min" : 0.41,
            "max" : 0.41
        },
        "Property3" : {
            "min" : 0.41,
            "max" : 0.41
        },
        "Property4" : {
            "min" : 0.41,
            "max" : 0.41
        }
    }
```

The name "properties" will remain constant, but the name of properties inside this can change and so can the number of properties. For example, this could be;

```
    {
    "Properties":
        "RandomNameOfProperty" : {
            "min" : 0.41,
            "max" : 0.41
        },
        "RandomNameOfProperty2" : {
            "min" : 0.41,
            "max" : 0.41
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Corrected JSON format.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  Valid JSON always begins with `[` or `{`.

Comment: The JSON begins with    {    .

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error: &e];
```

where data is your json data

Comment: Not that we cannot be sure that the outermost structure is a dictionary since the OP did not supply the compete JSON.

Comment: The outmost structure will never be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can transform you JSON to Objective-C

```
  NSString *jsonString = @"{"name": "My name" ....}"
  NSData *data = [@" " dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSMutableDictionary *json = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  NSError *er;
  json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error: &er];

  MyClassModel *my = [[MyClassModel alloc] init];
  my.name = json[@"name"];
  my.age = [json[@"age"] integerValue];
  my.type = json[@"type"];
```

There are also many libraries that does dynamic parsing and transformation for you.
**[JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel)** is really good one. With it you code would look like this -

```
NSString* json = @"{"name": "My name" ....}" //(fetch here JSON from Internet)
NSError* err = nil;
MyClassModel* country = [[MyClassModel alloc] initWithString:json error:&err];
```